# Instantiating class retains references

Tags: python, class, object, reference

In Python, I instantiate a class twice and store them into 2 different variables. Why does the second object contain a copy of the first object? I know it's a copy because I change the values in one object and it does not change the other. Example:

I have the following class:

```
class HistoricalData:
    dataPoints = {}
```

I then instantiate the class and fill dataPoints with values:

```
hd1 = HistoricalData()
hd1.dataPoints["channel1"] = 1
hd1.dataPoints["channel2"] = 2
hd1.dataPoints["channel3"] = 3
```

I then instantiate the class again and fill it with values again:

```
hd2 = HistoricalData()
hd2.dataPoints["channel1"] = 10
```

When I print the values from hd1.dataPoints and hd2.dataPoints I get the following:

```
{'channel1': 1, 'channel2': 2, 'channel3': 3}
{'channel1': 10, 'channel2': 2, 'channel3': 3}
```

The dictionary has a copy of the first in the second object because the value in channel1 was changed in the second but not the first.

I thought when you instantiate a class all values will be defaulted to what was defined in the class. Am I missing something?

Comment: You've made a mistake somewhere. Johhnyweb's answer is correct, as far as it goes, but you certainly will see the value changed to `10` in `dataPoints` for both instances if you run the code above. There is only one dictionary. "I know it's a copy because I change the values in one object and it does not change the other." -- well, that just isn't the case.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You've declared a [`class` variable](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects), not an [instance variable](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#instance-objects).

Class variables are shared among *all instances* of the `class`. This means that when you update one `HistoricalData` `object`, you update them all.

Instance variables are local to *each instance* of a `class`. These are typically initialised in the [`__init__()`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__) special method, which is called when *each instance* is created.

As such you should probably initialise `datapoints` like so to get the results you desire:

```
class HistoricalData(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.dataPoints = {}
```

Comment: If I added a new instance variable with a simple type like a string would this also need to be defined in __init__?

Comment: @DannyTsang: It's not about simplicity of types. `self.name = ''` would equally need to be *initialised* in `__init__()` (or similar) to be an *instance variable*.

Comment: @DannyTsang: Happy to help. Welcome to the StackOverflow community!